# Why undefined reference error despite -I (dash capital i) flag during compilation?

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I am compiling code that uses the external library `https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/quake/public/www/triangle.html`.
All the triangle source and object files are in ~/triangle/ folder. So I compile like this:

```
g++ -g sobel_aot_run.cpp sobel_x_out.a sobel_y_out.a support.a -ljpeg -lpng -std=c++11 -I ../include -I ../tools -I ~/triangle -lpthread -ldl -o sobel
```

Even though I have specified `-I ~/triangle`, running this command gives the following error:

```
/tmp/cc9AUEre.o: In function `main':
/home/zendevil/Halide/tutorial/sobel_aot_run.cpp:74: undefined reference to `triangulate(char*, triangulateio*, triangulateio*, triangulateio*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to compile this?

Comment: You say that the `triangle` code is still in source form. Did you compile it? If so, which `-l` argument is it supposed to in?

Comment: The `-l` option for the Unix/GNU-related linkers I am familiar with is for specifying a particular library file to use. `-lxyz` says to look for a file named `libxyz.a` or `libxyz.dylib` or possibly other suffixes for libraries, and `-lxyz.o` says to look for a file named `xyz.o`. `-l ~/triangle` does not tell the linker to use all object or library files in the directory `~/triangle/`. There is another option with a capital L, `-Ldirectory`, that tells the linker to include `directory` in the places it looks when it is looking for a library. But again, it does not tell the linker to use all…

Comment: … files in that directory. You still have to specify them individually. You can also list object and library files explicitly on the linker command line, without using `-l` or `-L`. For example, `~/triangle/*.o` might do what you need.

Comment: `-I` specifies a directory to look for headers in.

Comment: @EricPostpischil He's using `-I`, it just looked like `-l`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I have compiled it using make.

Comment: @john triangle readme says that TRILIBRARY is set automatically with make.

Comment: @EricPostpischil doing the *.o trick gives the same error in addition to a warning that path/to/triangle.o is not a directory.

Comment: I haven't used any -l flags for triangle in this command. All the -l flags in the command are for other things.

Comment: You need to link with the triangle library (that you built with make), just like you linked with libjpeg and libpng.

Comment: If you got a warning that `path/to/triangle.o` is not a directory, then you used it after a switch like `-L` or `-I` that expects a directory. To link an object file in with the program, just list it on the command line by itself, not after a switch that expects an argument to go with it.

Comment: @zengod Don't use `-I ~/triangle/*.o` or `-l ~/triangle/*.o`, just use `~/triangle/*.o`.

Answer (score 2):

`-I` only specifies to the compiler that you are searching in a directory for files to satisfy `#include` statements.

You now need to compile and link to the `triangulate` code that you are using.

Comment: How does one compile and link?

Comment: @zengod How do you think one compiles and links? Use your compiler!